# Moving reusable components outside project folder using Webpack React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, code-reuse

I am building an application using Webpack and React.

my package.json is :

```
{
  "name": "v1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'core');

var config = {
entry: APP_DIR + '/main.jsx',
output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'main.js'
},
module : {
    loaders : [
        {
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }
    ]
}
};

module.exports = config;
```

.babelrc:

```
{"presets" : ["es2015", "react"]}
```

These files are in a folder that is nested, something like:

```
root
| components
| | react
| | ember
| pages
| | | home
| | | about
```

The files I talked about are inside home. Basically home and about are 2 different npm projects and they have their own package.json as well as webpack.config.js and so on. But they need access to a react component called SearchBox in the file Searchbox.jsx the folder root/components/react.

When I try to access it from home , it shows an error saying:

> Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to
>   directory root/components/react

So how do I solve this issue, or you may suggest any other ways I may use to make reusable components that are outside the project folder

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.
What I did was install the node modules in the react folder as well through npm install and put the .babelrc file there as well. It was trying to load the node_modules from the react directory, not home directory for SearchBox.jsx.

So if someone else encounter this issue, the way to solve it is to install all the node dependencies of your external file in either the file's own directory, or in some parent directory of the file. Thats where it fetches it from.